# Multiplying two long numbers

Tags: c, multiplication

I have tried to multiply to numbers i.e. `10000` and `10000 + 1` through C program. But I am not getting the correct output.

```
printf("%lld",(100000)*(100001));
```

I have tried the above code on different compilers but I am getting same `1410165408` instead of `10000100000`.

Comment: It looks like you're on a platform where `int` is 32 bits (or thereabouts, but 32 is most likely).  You'll need to use a wider data type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, let's multiply

```
  int64_t a = 100000;
  int64_t b = 100001;
  int64_t c = a * b;
```

And we'll get (binary)

```
     1001010100000011010110101010100000 /* 10000100000 decimal */
```

but if you convert it to `int32_t`

```
  int32_t d = (int32_t) c;
```

you'll get the *last 32 bits* only (and *throw away* the top `10`):

```
       01010100000011010110101010100000 /* 1410165408 decimal */
```

A simplest way out, probably, is to declare both constants as *64-bit* values (`LL` suffix stands for `long long`):

```
  printf("%lld",(100000LL)*(100001LL));
```

Comment: Note that appending `LL` will ensure the constant has _at least_ a 64-bit width as `long long` must be that width or wider.

Answer (score 5):

In C, the type which is used for a calculation is determined from the type of the *operands*, not from the type where you store the result in.

Plain integer constants such as `100000` is of type `int`, because they will fit inside one. The multiplication of `100000 * 100001` will however not fit, so you get integer overflow and undefined behavior. Switching to `long` won't necessarily solve anything, because it might be 32 bit too.

In addition, printing an `int` with the `%lld` format specifier is also undefined behavior on most systems.

The root of all evil here is the crappy default types in C (called "primitive data types" for a reason). Simply get rid of them and all their uncertainties, and all your bugs will go away with them:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main(void) 
{
  printf("%"PRIu64, (uint64_t)100000 * (uint64_t)100001);
  return 0;
}
```

Or equivalent: `UINT64_C(100000) * UINT64_C(100001)`.

Comment: Detail;: If code uses `UINT64_C(100000) * ...`, which returns type `uint_least64_t`, then the specified matching printf specifier is  `PRIuLEAST64`

Answer (score 4):

Your two integers are `int`, that will make the result `int` too. That the `printf()` format specifier says `%lld`, which needs `long long int`, doesn't matter.

You can cast or use suffixes:

```
printf("%lld", 100000LL * 100001LL);
```

This prints `10000100000`. Of course there's still a limit, since the number of bits in a `long long int` is still constant.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this

```
long long int a = 100000;
long long int b = 100001;
printf("%lld",(a)*(b));
```

this will give the correct answer.

What you are doing is `(100000)*(100001)` i.e by default compiler takes `100000` into an integer and multiplies `100001` and stores it in `(int)`
But during printf it prints (int) as (long long int)